# Remove stale indexed pages from google search

Tags: feature-request, search

Results like:

- Recently Active Questions - Page 79783
- Unanswered Questions - Page 16641
- Hot 'javascript' Questions - Page 17559

are useless because the page has changed since it was indexed (so that clicking on the link takes you to a page that doesn't contain the search terms).

I think that dynamic lists such as the above should be marked to not be indexed to avoid stale indexing of pages by external search engines e.g. by using `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` in the markup.

Ideally mark pages 2 to ∞ as non-indexed, since page 1 could be exactly what the user is looking for (e.g. a search for `hot javascript questions` should probably return Page 1).

These results occur for general searches from Google. Also I often use Google instead of the inbuild search because it sometimes returns better results (by using `site:stackoverflow.com` as a Google search term). I do have to ignore a large number of stale list pages in the results though.